# Cannot read property 'str' of null typeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and there is a problem i can not solve when i want to get my location and then use Googlemap API to get the information about street and city.It always said that  Cannot read property 'str' of null
at... I don't know why.Can someone to help me?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-center',
  templateUrl: './center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./center.component.css']
})
export class CenterComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: Observable<any>;
  locationInfo: any;
  str: any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.dataSource = this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
      + 'latlng=' + this.str + '&key=AIzaSyC2wdo6kMAXpuhwuUa8fM4mCkDy_kZeWKY').map(Response => Response.json());
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPostion, this.showError);
    }
  }
  showPostion(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    this.str.bind(this);
    this.str = String(latitude + ',' + longitude);
    console.log(this.str);
  }
  showError() {
    console.log('Invalid Address !');
  }
  getData() {
    this.dataSource.subscribe(
      data => this.locationInfo = data
    );
    console.log(this.locationInfo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of where the problem is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind callbacks to the current class (TS doesn't do this for you)
Try `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPostion.bind(this), this.showError.bind(this));`
Als remove the `this.str.bind(this);` (bind is only for functions)

Comment: I want to make str global so that i can use it in other function like java.How can i do that?

Comment: That would completely depend on how your entire code is structured, how everything is compiled and where exactly you need the global. You might want to Google a bit about TypeScript and globals to see if you can find anything that resembles your situation.

Comment: I really appricate that.Thanks!